# How to deploy app developed in VueJS on a local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

I am new to NodeJS based application development, recently I have made a project using VueJs with Axios, primeVue and stuff like that, I want to test my application in "production" mode.

I have been working with Java for many years, and when Web applications are created they are deployed to an application server, like Glassfish for example; now I have that same mentality, I want to "mount" my application for production, but I can't find the way I expect it, for example, if I have two or more Vue applications, they are when executing the command

```
npm run serve
```

the application runs on the default port

> http://localhost:8080/

and if I want to "mount" another application and run the same, it changes port

> http://localhost:8081/

and I want it to run on the same port in the following way:

**App1**

> http://localhost:8080/app1

**App2**

> http://localhost:8080/app2

and so on if I have more Vue apps, just like what happens with Java Web apps.

Will there be an application "manager" where I can start, stop or deploy my applications (ie manage them)?

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "labquimico",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "chart.js": "3.3.2",
        "core-js": "3.6.5",
        "papaparse": "^5.3.1",
        "primeflex": "3.0.0",
        "primeicons": "5.0.0",
        "primevue": "3.9.1",
        "prismjs": "1.9.0",
        "vue": "3.2.9",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
        "vuex": "^4.0.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the purpose of nginx, etc web server in a setup. `serve` is for development only. After you use `build`, /dist is a bunch of static assets, it doesn't matter if it's Vue or anything else

Comment: @EstusFlask I get nowhere with your answer :(

Comment: Run `npm build` and serve static files as any other files with a web server in a way you need. It's not specific to Vue or Node at this point. `serve` is for development only, as I said, you shouldn't consider it for production purpose

Comment: @EstusFlask so can i deploy it to the glassfish as a normal web app? As I said I am new to this I have investigated but it is difficult for me.

Comment: I didn't deal with glassfish. You may achieve this with application server if it's capable of serving static files but I'd expect this to be done with web server (nginx) because it's more efficient. Any way, built Vue app is a collection of files that need to be served to a browser, one way or another. The only thing that is specific to Vue (actually, to SPA in general) is that a server needs to be configured to serve index.html instead of 404 pages if you need to support client-side router.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have already investigated and it turns out that I cannot install nginx because my local server is Windows, any other alternative?

Comment: You can run nginx on windows (even if you couldn't, it would be doable with windows wsl and ubuntu), it's a must for a good webdev setup. And you can run any other webserver like apache.